# Convergence of $ \int_ 0^\infty x^2\sin(x^4)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

Prove $ \int_ 0^\infty x^2\sin(x^4)dx$ converges.

It seems really close to the form of Fresnel integral $ \int_ 0^\infty \sin(x^2)dx$, which made me suspect it works the same.

Furthermore after entering some integrals in wolfarm alpha with some modification it seems that the integral $ \int_ 0^\infty x^k\sin x^{2n} dx$ converges when $k < 2n$, so an explanation why its starts to diverge when $k > 2n$ would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718960/convergence-of-int-limits-1-inftyx-alpha-sinx-betadx?rq=1

Comment: @RobertZ oh thank you i did not find it, sorry for the duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

**Showing Convergence**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^2\sin\left(x^4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac14\int_0^\infty x^{-1/4}\sin(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\[4pt]
&=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{4x^{1/4}}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{4x^{1/4}}+\frac1{16}\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{5/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\[4pt]
&=\frac1{16}\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{5/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: substitute $x\mapsto x^{1/4}$
$(2)$: integrate by parts
$(3)$: the limits are zero

The integral converges by comparison to $\frac1{16}\int_0^1\frac{\frac12x^2}{x^{5/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x+\frac1{16}\int_1^\infty\frac2{x^{5/4}}\,\mathrm{d}x$

---

**Evaluation**
$$
\require{cancel}
\newcommand{\Im}{\operatorname{Im}}
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty x^2\sin\left(x^4\right)\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\frac14\Im\left(\int_0^\infty z^{-1/4}e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)\tag{4}\\
&=\frac14\Im\left(\int_0^{i\infty} z^{-1/4}e^{iz}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)\tag{5}\\
&=\frac14\Im\left(e^{i3\pi/8}\int_0^\infty z^{-1/4}e^{-z}\,\mathrm{d}z\right)\tag{6}\\[3pt]
&=\frac14\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}8\right)\Gamma\left(\frac34\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(4)$: substitute $x=z^{1/4}$ and $\sin(z)=\Im\left(e^{iz}\right)$
$(5)$: the integral along $[0,R]\cup\cancel{Re^{i\pi[0,1/2]}}\cup[iR,0]$ is zero
$(6)$: substitute $z\mapsto iz$
$(7)$: evaluate

Answer (score 3):

There is clearly no convergence issue near $0$ so we need only consider the convergence of $\int_ 1^\infty x^2\sin(x^4)dx$.

Let $M>1$. Note that $$\int_ 1^M x^2\sin(x^4)dx =\frac 14 \int_1^{M^4} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1/4}}dx=\frac14\cos(1)-\frac14\frac{\cos(M^4)}{M^{1/4}}-\frac{1}{16}\int_1^{M^4}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{5/4}}dx$$

- $\dfrac{\cos(M^4)}{M^{1/4}}$ goes to $0$ as $M\to \infty$
- $\int_1^{M^4}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^{5/4}}dx$ is absolutely convergent, hence convergent.

Hence the existence of $\lim_{M\to \infty} \int_ 1^M x^2\sin(x^4)dx$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici There is none, so I'm free to let the integral start at $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I misread it !! Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with only one integration by parts: for every $M>1$ one has
$$
\int_1^M x^2 \sin(x^4)\, dx
= \frac{1}{4} \int_1^M \frac{1}{x}\, [4x^3\sin(x^4)]\, dx
= -\frac{\cos M^4}{4M} + \cos 1 -\frac{1}{4} \int_1^M \frac{\cos x^4}{x^2}\, dx.
$$
The last integral is absolutely convergent, since $\left|\frac{\cos x^4}{x^2}\right| \leq \frac{1}{x^2}$, and $\left|\frac{\cos M^4}{4M}\right| \leq \frac{1}{4M} \to 0$ as $M\to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed the integral is convergent by the substitution $x\mapsto x^{1/4}$ and Dirichlet's test. Additionally:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2\sin(x^4)\,dx = \frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1/4}}\,dx\stackrel{\mathcal{L}}{=} \frac{1}{4\,\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{s^{3/4}(1+s^2)}\tag{1}$$
leads to:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2\sin(x^4)\,dx = \frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{1+u^8}=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{8\, \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)}}.\tag{2}$$

Comment: how do you get the equality $\mathcal L$ ?

Comment: @Surb: the usual way - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_integrals_over_the_positive_real_axis

Comment: The Laplace trasform of $\sin(x)$ is $\frac{1}{1+s^2}$, the inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{1}{x^{1/4}}$ is $\frac{1}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)\, s^{3/4}}$.

Comment: Indeed, it's a nice way :-) (but more sophisticated)

Comment: Just one thing (I don't know well laplace transform), why $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1/4}}dx=\int_0^\infty \mathcal L(\sin(x))\mathcal L(x^{-1/4})$ ?

Comment: Such property of the Laplace transform is proved on the linked Wikipedia page. $\int_{0}^{+\infty} f(x)\,g(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty} (\mathcal{L} f)(s)\,(\mathcal{L}^{-1} g)(s)\,ds$ as soon as $f$ and $g$ are sufficiently well-behaved.